# Flash - Firefox issue

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, firefox, wmode

I realised that if I do have a flash object and do not include a 'wmode' attribute, I will not be able to overlay HTML because the flash will always play on top. But if I do include a 'wmode:transparent' , the flash object completely disappears in firefox, whereas if I use 'wmode:opaque' , I get a white box in place of the Flash object.

I've looked at many forums - many questions - but somehow everyone's problem gets resolved when they use one of the aforementioned attributes. So....HELP !!!

Note: using either attribute works in IE.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are coming from a Flash perspective - I am not sure exactly how you generate your HTML wrapper, but if you use Flex, you get something like the code that follows.
I know that it generates a transparent wrapper, because I had to present it to a client as transparent for a deliverable a couple of days ago. Click [here for the demo I used](http://xanthos.soliantconsulting.com/CAECoverFlow/CAECoverFlow.html).

Here is my exact html wrapper code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

```
This application was built using Adobe Flex, an open source framework
for building rich Internet applications that get delivered via the
Flash Player or to desktops via Adobe AIR. 

Learn more about Flex at http://flex.org 
// -->
<head>
    <title>${title}</title>         
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <!-- Include CSS to eliminate any default margins/padding and set the height of the html element and 
         the body element to 100%, because Firefox, or any Gecko based browser, interprets percentage as 
         the percentage of the height of its parent container, which has to be set explicitly.  Initially, 
         don't display flashContent div so it won't show if JavaScript disabled.
    -->
    <style type="text/css" media="screen"> 
        html, body  { height:100%; }
        body { margin:0; padding:0; overflow:auto; text-align:center; }   
        #flashContent { display:none; }
    </style>

    <!-- Enable Browser History by replacing useBrowserHistory tokens with two hyphens -->
    <!-- BEGIN Browser History required section ${useBrowserHistory}>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="history/history.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="history/history.js"></script>
    <!${useBrowserHistory} END Browser History required section -->  

    <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xhttp=new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else // for older IE 5/6
        {
            xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xhttp.open("GET","ShowcaseConfig.xml",false);
        xhttp.send("");
        xmlDoc=xhttp.responseXML;
        var xmlString=xhttp.responseText;

        <!-- For version detection, set to min. required Flash Player version, or 0 (or 0.0.0), for no version detection. --> 
        var swfVersionStr = "${version_major}.${version_minor}.${version_revision}";
        <!-- To use express install, set to playerProductInstall.swf, otherwise the empty string. -->
        var xiSwfUrlStr = "${expressInstallSwf}";
        var flashvars = {};
        var params = {};
        params.quality = "high";
        params.bgcolor = "${bgcolor}";
        params.allowscriptaccess = "sameDomain";
        params.allowfullscreen = "true";
        params.wmode = "transparent";
        var attributes = {};
        attributes.id = "${application}";
        attributes.name = "${application}";
        attributes.align = "middle";
        swfobject.embedSWF(
            "${swf}.swf", "flashContent", 
            "${width}", "${height}", 
            swfVersionStr, xiSwfUrlStr, 
            flashvars, params, attributes);
        <!-- JavaScript enabled so display the flashContent div in case it is not replaced with a swf object. -->
        swfobject.createCSS("#flashContent", "display:block;text-align:left;");
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- SWFObject's dynamic embed method replaces this alternative HTML content with Flash content when enough 
         JavaScript and Flash plug-in support is available. The div is initially hidden so that it doesn't show
         when JavaScript is disabled.
    -->
    <div style="background-image:url(desert_short.jpg); border: 2px solid #000000;">


    <div id="flashContent">
        <p>
            To view this page ensure that Adobe Flash Player version 
            ${version_major}.${version_minor}.${version_revision} or greater is installed. 
        </p>
        <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
            <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash Player" />
        </a>
    </div>

    <noscript>
        <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="${width}" height="${height}" id="${application}">
            <param name="movie" value="${swf}.swf" />
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="${bgcolor}" />
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
            <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
            <param name="wmode" value="transparent"> 
            <!--[if !IE]>
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="${swf}.swf" width="${width}" height="${height}">
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="${bgcolor}" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
            <![endif]-->
            <!--[if gte IE 6]>
                <p> 
                    Either scripts and active content are not permitted to run or Adobe Flash Player version
                    ${version_major}.${version_minor}.${version_revision} or greater is not installed.
                </p>
            <![endif]-->
                <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
                    <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash Player" />
                </a>
            <!--[if !IE]>
            </object>
            <![endif]-->
        </object>
    </noscript>
```

Hope this helps. Check my blog [here](http://www.soliantconsulting.com/blog/category/adobe-flex/) for some other nice examples and components.

Cheers,

Casp